# Maximum length of a String Preference in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, preferences

I would like to know what is the maximum length of a String when saving in the classic [preferences System](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Preferences):

```
var prefs = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"]
                .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefBranch);
prefs.setCharPref("com.exemple.namespace.preference", potentiallyLongString);
```

Couldn't find it in official documentation.

Note: I tried to type in more than 255, it works on Firefox 3.6, but I'm looking for a documented answer which would certify that length `L` works since version `V`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no documentation on that. You shouldn't store unreasonably large strings in prefs -- if you're not sure if it will be reasonable, it's likely not a pref.

Comment: Agreed, yet I'm wondering about an order of magnitude to know what's "reasonable" and what's not. E.g. if I want to store a short list of FQDNs, should I store the number and use individual preferences for the values or can I store them in a single string preference, separated by commas? If I'm agranteed I can store around 4K chars and the typical list is less than 10 domain names, I'd use the second which is simpler to implement…

Comment: @streetpc: I don't think there's an actual limit in the order of thousands characters, and since the preferences system is quite stable there probably weren't many changes in the recent versions. So you could try it and use it.

Answer (score 2):

Since there was no documentation, I just though of trying it anyway (at the most it'd have crashed my browser). I tried to the extent of 1,51,276 characters - and it worked perfectly fine. Trust me, I even matched the characters to test the reliability. :) Of course, doesn't mean you should use it regularly to those extents. ;). Just to give you an idea, that'd be around 30,000 words of English language, and has more number of characters than the whole script of the Movie Matrix (part 1).

I didn't try for more, as Notepad++ had started becoming slow in copying and pasting those many characters.

(Test Environment: Firefox 24, Windows 7 64 bit)

Edit: While I was trying this, I also noticed that even though it works for enormously large values, after some 4000 characters, Firefox starts giving a performance warning in the Error Console. So take what you want to from this.